# How to know old id of item in recycle bin?

Tags: list, item, recycle-bin

I need know old id of item in recycle bin or is there any way how to save its id in this item before deleting. When item is deleted, a new SPRecycleBinItem is created in Recycle Bin. And the only saved information about old item is DirName. But I need know more information.

**[EDIT]**

I have solved this issue. There is such property as LeafName in SPRecycleBinItem, which is the same as earlier Id in SPListItem for files (not for folders). If SPListItem was a file, then its LeafName would be "id" + "_.000" after deleting; If SPListItem was a folder, then its LeafName would be earlier Name of SPListItem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this issue. There is such property as LeafName in SPRecycleBinItem, which is the same as earlier Id in SPListItem for files (not for folders). If SPListItem was a file, then its LeafName would be "id" + "_.000" after deleting; If SPListItem was a folder, then its LeafName would be earlier Name of SPListItem.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

SPRecycleBinItem.ID is not same as deletedItem.UniqueID. I have checked it. So you can't use them to identify deleted item in recycle bin. You can expiriment with DirName and LeafName, but there at least 3 different cases: item is folder, item is file, item is ordinary item.

Answer (score 0):

The SPRecycleBinItem has the unique GUID which is the same before and after deletion. Therefore, you can retrieve it using the code below:

```
SPRecycleBinItemCollection itemColl = web.GetRecycleBinItems(q);
foreach (SPRecycleBinItem item in itemColl)
{
    Guid[] id = new Guid[1];
    id[0] = item.ID; //Gets the GUID of the item.

}
```

Comment: Yes, I know about GUID, but i need retrieve an old id of item, that located earlier in a list.

Comment: it it really existing in the Recyle bin any more?